# Boost::message_queue::receive/send not working with latest version

Tags: c++, boost

When I was using Boost 1.53.0, I used send and receive like this:

```
int i=0;
msg_queue.send(&i, sizeof(i), 0);

int number;
unsigned int priority = 0;
boost::interprocess::message_queue::size_type recvd_size;
msg_queue.receive(&number, sizeof(number), recvd_size, priority);
```

Now using latest version 1.65.1, I get an invalid argument error, the problem seems to be ***sizeof()***.

The Boost documentation didn't change between version 1.53.0 and 1.65.1.
[Message_queue Doc](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/interprocess/synchronization_mechanisms.html#interprocess.synchronization_mechanisms.message_queue)

The signature of send and receive requires a ***size_type*** where I used ***sizeof()***, I tried to cast it to ***size_type***, use a ***size_type*** variable, but at runtime I get a library error doing so.

Thanks for helping out.

Edit:
To the request of a user, here are the different error messages I get depending of what I tried.

```
#1 attempt: msg_queue.receive(&number, sizeof(number), recvd_size, priority);
#1 Error at compile time: Invalid arguments 'Canditates are: void send(const void *, ?, unsigned int)'
#1 Comment: Same error for Message_Queue::Send()
```

The same code, with earlier version, I was able to send and receive values.

Comment: What is the full, complete error message?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the real compiler error, I assume that the problem is with `priority` instead. It's supposed to be passed by lvalue-reference, but the type doesn't match (should be unsigned):

```
#include <boost/interprocess/ipc/message_queue.hpp>

namespace bip = boost::interprocess;

bip::message_queue msg_queue(bip::open_or_create, "bla", 10, 10240);

int main() {
    int i=0;
    msg_queue.send(&i, sizeof(i), 0);

    int number;
    unsigned priority = 0;
    boost::interprocess::message_queue::size_type recvd_size;
    msg_queue.receive(&number, sizeof(number), recvd_size, priority);
}
```

Indeed Boost didn't change between [1.53](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost/interprocess/message_queue_t.html#idp56401728-bb) and [1.65.1](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/boost/interprocess/message_queue_t.html#idp65375216-bb) but perhaps your code or compiler did.

See it **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f69fde6840582827)</kbd>**

Comment: Indeed, priority is unsigned, I just made a mistake while writting on StackOverflow. What do you mean by "without seeing the real compiler error"?